# cross compiling using code blocks using arm-linux-gnueabi

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, toolchain

Any advice to fix the error?

I'm using code blocks with wx widgets 2.8 and the program compiles good when I use the GNU GCC compiler.

Now I want to compile and be able to run on ARM (beaglebone black), but I got the following error. I changed the toolchain settings to point to arm-linux-gnueabi.

```
> -------------- Build: Debug in assignment (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler for ARM)---------------
> 
> arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -g
> -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DWX_PRECOMP -g -Iinclude -c assignmentApp.cpp -o obj/Debug/assignmentApp.o In file included from
> /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/memory.h:16:0,
>                  from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/object.h:20,
>                  from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/wx.h:16,
>                  from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/wxprec.h:68,
>                  from ./wx_pch.h:14,
>                  from <command-line>:0: /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/string.h:827:13: error: ‘wxChar&
> wxString::operator[](unsigned int)’ cannot be overloaded
>      wxChar& operator[](unsigned int n)
>              ^ /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/string.h:824:13: error: with ‘wxChar& wxString::operator[](wxStringBase::size_type)’
>      wxChar& operator[](size_type n)
>              ^
```

--edit

ok ill try my best.

first I created a new wxwidget project on code blocks. the defaults project is a hello world GUI with help and quit button.

I next configured a arm compiler by downloading arm-linux-gnueabihf package.

under the compiler settings, i selected

```
C compiler:               arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
c++ compiler:             arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
linker for dynamic libs:  arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
linker for static libs:   arm-linux-eabihf-ar
debugger:                 (default) --invalid debugger--
resource compiler:        (empty)
make program:             make
```

then I go to code blocks menu and click projects -> build options
select myHellowworld project and select my arm compiler i just configured above.

I click Build and I get the error in the first post, this happens for my other projects too.

Comment: Give us an [MCVE] please!

Comment: I have added it more information

Comment: Read the link, don’t just throw in more information.